# What is the Pythonic way to write this loop?

Tags: python

```
for jr in json_reports:
  jr['time_created'] = str(jr['time_created'])
```

Comment: What don't you like about it?  What's your concern?  What do you think could be improved?

Comment: I thought there might be a one-liner, sort of like a list comprehension, but I geuss that doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks to me that you're already there

Answer (score 5):

That would be the pythonic way to write the loop if you need to assign it to the same list.

If you just want to pull out strings of all `time_created` indices in each element of `json_reports`, you can use a list comprehension:

```
strings = [str(i['time_created']) for i in json_reports]
```